# How to change the text of a Bootstrap 3 button with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to retrieve button text inside tag button?

Example HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="dislikes" value="notThisValue">DISLIKES<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span></button>
```

My jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dislikes').click(function() {
        $("#dislikes").val('Hello World');
    })
});
```

I need to change the text **DISLIKES** to **YOU DISLIKE IT**. My jQuery has to change the inner text of the button not the value "notThisValue".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reason you are not able to change the text is that you are changing its value using `.val()`. Instead you need to use `.text()` to change tag's text.

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#like').click(function() {
 $("#like").text('YOU DISLIKE IT');
})
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) or [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dislikes').click(function() {
        $(this).text('Hello World');
    })
});
```